# Dev and prod on the same database- dev version active for IOS

Tags: posts, mysql, customization

I'm looking at a problem on a WordPress site I didn't build and the company that did are no longer operating.

The site is fairly basic with no user membership this etc etc.

The site holds all its content and configuration in the wp_ tables, so is properly database driven.  The site holds development and production data in the same database.

The problem is that when a user on an iOS device clicks on the contact us button instead of displaying the contact page it shows a logon to the old companies development site.  If you cancel the logon a couple of times it will go and then you are redirected to the correct contact page.

I've looked through the wp_posts data and can't see anything obvious that I could change.

I'm guessing there is a database entry somewhere that is just being used for iOS devices and is incorrectly configured to show the old development site contact page.

Nobody noticed the error until a user informed them so it's probably been there since the beginning rather than a problem with the server, ios update etc.

Does anyone know where I should look? I'm guessing a probably won't show this error because it is not really an error, more a feature that is activated to enable development work/testing and should not be.

Comment: Without access to the code, here are things you could try: search the database for any mention of the URL to the old development site. If you don't find it in the database, then it is most likely in the theme. If you download a local copy of the theme and use a text editor with "find in files" capability, you can search for the URL in the theme. If it's not there, then it is in either a plugin or some very complex server setup. Again you can download the plugins and search through the files for the URL.

Comment: Thanks.  I've searched code- no hits.  The DB contains hundreds of links for the dev site.  How can I narrow it down to the ones that are pertinent to the rendering of the following <LI> on IOS- `<li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-38 current_page_item menu-item-45"><a href="http://domain123.com/contact/">Get in touch</a></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menus are manually managed in WordPress. Log into wp-admin, and there are 2 places you can update these links.

1. Appearance > Menus - select each menu in turn until you find the link in question, then update it. It's best to add a Page (or Post or whatever content type) straight from this admin interface; then it pulls from the database ID and doesn't hard-code the URL like you are running into here.
2. Appearance > Customize - go to Menus, then same process, browse through all the menus until you find the problem links and replace them.